# (Ruby on Rails) Pass array in partial as collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I have a function:

```
def self.get_component(component_name, properties{})
   render :partial => component_name :collection => properties{}
end
```

That is meant to render a partial from the argument 'component_name' and then pass the array of properties for said component via a collection.

I have a class calling said method with

```
get_component('members_card/display', properties{member_name => "Jason"})
```

Which I haven't actually checked yet, but i've been told I don't actually have to explicitly set the data in the array. I finally have the partial:

```
<div class="members-card">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="card">
            <img class="card__profile" alt="display name" src="">
            <div class="card__details">
                <h4 class="card__title"> <%= ??? %> </h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But I don't have a clue how to actually call the data in the array i've set as a collection for the partial, so that i could populate the name.

I see things such as @properties or properties.member_name, would one of these be the correct solution, and if so, why?

Comment: the collection you are sending is a Hash. Actually, we use Instance Variables like [at]posts or [at]properties and pass that to the partial collection. At the front end side you have to call the Hash with the key.

Pls go through this [link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html)

Comment: I see you come from a PHP background... "Arrays" in PHP are like a fuzzy mix between arrays and hashes. Learn the difference between an `Array` and a `Hash`, and doing this in Ruby (or practically any other non-PHP language) will make much more sense :)

Comment: This makes sense! I was under the impression that associative arrays were a thing in every language, but I guess i've been in the PHP bubble for too long.

Comment: A ruby hash *is* essentially an associative array (technically it's implemented as a doubly linked list). Arrays in PHP aren't even true associative arrays, as you can only use integers or strings as the "keys" - whereas in ruby, you cn use *any* object. Honestly, PHP's implementation of "arrays" is *not* a standard implementation to learn from ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use something like:

```
properties = ['a','b','c']
render partial: 'my_partial', locals: {
  my_collection: properties
}
```

Then in `my_partial.html.erb`:

```
<% my_collection.each do |collection| %>
...
<% end %>
```